# How to get rid of 2 pixel margin around full width/height iframes?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that I want to take up the full width and height of the browser:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/index.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately there's a 2 pixel margin around it causing an ugly thin line on the top and left, as well as scrollbars to appear. I've tried this without luck:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/index.html" width="100%" height="100%" style="margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliminate the border too:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/index.html" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>
```

Comment: This still isn't quite right.  There's no ugly border, but the content is still offset by 2px.

Comment: @AleksG - You're probably seeing margin/padding on the body/html. Works fine at http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2hQkg/